# Liquibase - different versions of file

Tags: liquibase, rollback, devops, changeset

I am orchestrating an automatic delivery process using GIT, Bamboo, Ansible and Liquibase.

I am having some issues trying to use Liquibase rollback feature. Basically I have the same files, my change set master and the version files (each having its own rollback section), in two different places, say an "upgrade" folder and a "rollback" folder. Even though the files are the same, the rollback simply does not work. Illustrating:

```
+ deployment_folder
    + update
        - changeset-master.xml
        - changeset-1.0.0.xml
        - changeset-1.0.1.xml
    + rollback
        - changeset-master.xml
        - changeset-1.0.0.xml
        - changeset-1.0.1.xml
```

The files have exactly the same content.

Running liquibase updates and tagging is fine:

```
$>liquibase --username=USR --password=*** --classpath=./ojdbc7.jar --driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID --changeLogFile=update/changeset-master.xml update
$>liquibase --username=USR --password=*** --classpath=./ojdbc7.jar --driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID --changeLogFile=update/changeset-master.xml tag 1.0.0
$>liquibase --username=USR --password=*** --classpath=./ojdbc7.jar --driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID --changeLogFile=update/changeset-master.xml update
$>liquibase --username=USR --password=*** --classpath=./ojdbc7.jar --driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID --changeLogFile=update/changeset-master.xml tag 1.0.1
```

However, when trying to rollback from 1.0.1 to 1.0.0 using the change set master in **rollback** folder it says "Liquibase Rollback Successful" but the changes are not rolled back. the rollbackSQL command also does not display any relevant SQL statement other than the DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK updates.

```
$>liquibase --username=USR --password=*** --classpath=./ojdbc7.jar --driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID --changeLogFile=rollback/changeset-master.xml rollback 1.0.0
```

Looks like the file has to be exactly the same (for checksum I suppose), which is a show blocker in my case, where I have to constantly pull versions from my source control system, so the files will never be "the same", although they have the same content. Is there any way to disable this verification in Liquibase? Currently I am using Liquibase 3.4.2.

Comment: I forgot to mention if I ran the rollback with the same file, it works.

Comment: Checkout [`logicalFilePath`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/databasechangelog.html). As far as I remember the checksum includes the filename with full path. So even if you have the same file in a different folder it is considered to be differently. Using `logicalFilePath` should avoid this.

Comment: Jens, you got it. That's exactly it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase rollback doesn't work this way, you need to specify rollback instructions in <rollback> section of your script and execute it with rollback command: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html

UPD: Liquibase uses id based on changeset file name, change id and author id to identify changes. If you apply `<change id="1" author="dbf">...</change>` from file f1.xml it's 'virtual' id is `<f1.xml, 1, dbf>`. When you run f2.xml with the same content for rollback the id it calculates is `<f2.xml, 1, dbf>` so it doesn't match the first id and nothing is rolled back.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear, but every changeset inside the versioned files has its own rollback section.